# Why ProgressBar stop animation While Swapping the Layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I am using a linear layout. That include an progressbar.xml  that show a indicator to user for wait. There are 2 buttons that say "abc"  and "xyz".   When currently "abc" button is in pressed state. When the activity start it show progress-bar **(progressbar is in animation by this property android:indeterminate="true")**  to user.  User click  "xyz"  button. I store the reference of progress-bar layout by   findViewById(int id);   And then  INFLATE using LayoutInflater  another   data.xml  form layout.  I remove  mainLinearview.removeAllView();
Then add mainLinearview.addView(dataview);
And It display other data. Once agin when the user click the "abc" button same step are applied to mainLinearview.addView(progressbar).

> **Main problem is this time progressbar is not animating**  Can you please help?  1 more thing I search how to change color of progressbar. But I did not found any thing good. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call this when the progress bar appears again and it should be animating again.

```
public static void resumeProgressBarAnimation(ProgressBar pb) {
    if (pb.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I am interchanging a Button with an indeterminate ProgressBar, so I took a look to [ProgressBar source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob_plain;f=core/java/android/widget/ProgressBar.java;hb=HEAD) and they use `startAnimation()` and `stopAnimation()` for indeterminate ProgressBar, but the methods are not visible for an Activity so the quick workaround I'm using is at `setVisibility(int)` they start and stop the animation based on visibility state of the ProgressBar, but the key about this is that you must stop the animation before you change the layout and start it when the ProgressBar parent layout come back... so finally what I did is:

```
/**
 * Replace a button with the specified view. The view will be set
 * with the button layout parameters. Use {@link #revert(HeaderButton, View)}
 * to rollback this operation
 * @param button
 * @param with
 */
public void replace(HeaderButton button, View with){
    with.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mHeaderView.replace(button, with);
}

/**
 * Restores a button that was previously replaced
 * @param button
 * @param with
 */
public void revert(HeaderButton button, View with){
    with.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mHeaderView.revert(button, with);
}
```

The passed `with` View currently is an indeterminate ProgressBar and the button is replaced OnClick and reverted when the background process finishes.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

First, posting your code will HELP you to GET help. It sounds that you have not properly edited your manifest file to actually display the ProgressBar, so start with posting what that looks like. It's rather simple.

Check your Activity class...have you set the visibility to be true?